# Laravel Middleware: Where should you put it as a best practice?

Tags: laravel

I was reading the Laravel documentation about middleware and at a certain point it said: "[it would be more convenient to specify middleware within your controller's constructor.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#controller-middleware)"

I always assigned the middleware to the routes in the routing files because it felt easier to understand which functions were affected by the middleware.

I was wondering if there was a specific reason why the documentation says to put the middleware assignments directly in the Controller constructor or if it was just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1):

Its all depends on your own choice.

I always prefer to use middleware in route as a group, which keeps things centralized and I can find them easily.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['middleware1']], function () {
    // your routes under middleware1
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['middleware2']], function () {
    // your routes under middleware2
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a matter of preference, i like to assign the middleware to the route so i don't have to exclude certain methods in the controller plus it's much easier to know which routes use the middleware just by looking at the routes file.

Answer (score 0):

**it is more convenient to specify middleware within your controller's constructor.**

This simply means you have more control over each methods if you use it in your controller's constructor, so that you can specify certain rules in method levels.

But when you are assigning to the routes you can only control the routes rules.

Comment: Not really. Instead of spreading middlewares in too many files, why not simply keep middlewares together in one place? Like inside a route file. web, api, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question, as mentioned before in most cases it is a decision made by the team you are working with. 
From my own personal experience, I can only explain to you why we choose to use middleware definition in routes file instead of a controller.

1. In large applications, there are many cases of a dozen controllers.
   With that being said, there can be cases where you have to change some middleware name. If you define it on route group you would have to change only one line of code, but if you define it in a constructor you would have to go to every controller and change it.
2. Some companies are using controllers to inject certainly classes into it. There can be a huge amount of injecting and assigning classes in the constructor itself.
   That's why defining crucial checks should not be happening on this level of code.